# Cosa significa "in stralucido" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Artemisia*, di Anna Banti, ho letto:

> A terra, sostenuta dal piede forcuto di un arcolaio d'argento, la Sant'Agata, **in stralucido**, pareva corrucciata irrespettosamente.

Di questa Sant'Agata il romanzo spiega un po' prima:

> Precedeva la pittrice un maggiordomo vecchissimo che strasciava i piedi, la seguiva un paggio cresciutello, con le ginocchia nodose scoperte: e portava, avvolto in un drappo, il complimento, che era poi una Sant'Agata dalle poppe mozze, curiosa scelta di Orazio.

Si tratta di un dono che fanno i Gentileschi alla regina Enrichetta di Francia, sposa del re Carlo I d'Inghilterra.

La mia domanda è sul significato di "in stralucido" nel primo brano. Ha qualcosa a che vedere con la [tecnica decorativa](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stralucido) spiegata da Wikipedia?

Comment: Penso sia più un'iperbole di "tirata a lucido".

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: E cosa significa "tirata a lucido"?

Comment: essere (eleganti / preparati) per una grande occasione / "con il vestito della domenica" / "essere in tiro" / "tirati a lustro"

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: Ma si riferisce a una pittura di Sant'Agata che i Gentileschi hanno dato in donno alla regina.

Comment: La Santa nella rappresentazione potrebbe essere in abiti di lustro, che stonano con la sua posizione di santa, creando un distacco. Ma è un'ipotesi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo stralucido è una tecnica artistica, usata di solito per le ceramiche e cotti vari, praticamente lucidando prima della cottura l'oggetto avrà una maggiore riflettanza. Di solito non lo si fa su tutto l'oggetto perché è una tecnica usata per dare contrasto vicino a zone più opache. Se si tratta di questa allora o non è un dipinto su tela o è un busto.
Potrebbe anche riferirsi a come la luce colpisce l'oggetto, di sbieco, tra i vari riflessi del dipinto l'espressione della santa che così potrebbe sembrare un po' diversa.

Comment: E si usa anche per la pittura?

Comment: Eventualmente è una tecnica con cui si lavora il materiale su cui si dipinge dopo, e non si dipingeva solo sulla tela. Non ricordo nessuna Sant'Agata dipinta da loro, non posso cercare in rete al momento, sei sicura è un dipinto e non un busto? Cmq riferendosi alla santa martirizzata non credo proprio abbia a che fare con abiti dipinti.

Comment: Veramente non lo so, il libro non lo dice.

Comment: ho corretto la risposta per essere un poco più chiaro.

Comment: Grazie, @ErikvanDoren, penso che così si capisca meglio.